# Why body height is not 100% while using min-height property with 100% value

Tags: html, css

I have a page at

```
http://uberhealth.co/register.php
```

I have set the property to set the `min-height` to `100%` but still as you can see the footer is not at bottom and thus the height is not getting set to `100%`. how can i fix this?

#### Update

I have already given there

```css
html, body{
   height:100%;
}
```

and a container class for body

```css
.cbody-full { min-height:100%; }
```

Comment: What do you want to do? `.cbody-full` is 100% of height. The Footer is inside of that element. If you want it on the bottom, add `positon: absolute; bottom:0;` or place it beyond `.cbody-full`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though you've set a `min-height` (percentage) value for the `<html>` element, it doesn't have a explicit `height` value. Hence, the `min-height` property is not working for the `<body>` element properly.

From the **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)**:

> `min-height`
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage
>   value is treated as 0.

You could set a `height` of `100%` for the `<html>` element, and `min-height: 100%;` for the `<body>`.

```css
html { height: 100%; }
body { min-height: 100%; }
```

### Update #1

Here's my attempt to fix your layout issue.

First note that you have to specify the `height` of the *parent* element, if want to use `min-height` for the *child* element.

You have multiple wrappers inside each other, changed all the `min-height: 100%` declarations to `height: 100%` (including the `html`, `body`, ...); and use `min-height: 100%` for the `.cbody-full > container` element.

Then, you may face the vertical scrollbar. That's because the computed `height` of the **header** and the **footer** is added to `100%` of the height of the screen (In fact the  `.cbody-full > container` element has the height of `100%`).

You could fix that, by adding a negative top/bottom `margin` to the `.cbody-full > container` element:

```css
.cbody-full > container {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  margin-top: -55px;
}
```

But, this cause the container goes over the header and/or the footer. In order to fix that, you could set a top/bottom `padding` to the container and use `box-sizing: border-box` to calculate the width and height of the box including the paddings and borders:

```css
.cbody-full > container {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: -55px;
  padding-top: 55px;
}
```

Just one more thing, you probably need to set `z-index` property for the header and footer elements, as follows:

```css
#navbar, /* The header (navigation in this case) */
.footer { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

### Update #2

If you consider using *Ryan fait's* **[sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)**, note that the *footer* shouldn't be inside of the `.cbody-full` element, it should be beside that. That's why it doesn't stay at the bottom of the page.

Hence, you could change your markup as follows:

```
<body>
    <nav id="navbar"></nav>
    <div class="cbody-full"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Then, follow the above approach for `height` and `min-height` properties, as well as `position` and `z-index` for the *navigation* and *footer*. Finally use the following for the `.cbody-full` element:

```css
.cbody-full {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: -55px;
  padding-top: 55px;
}
```

Comment: Or, to rephrase that: `100%` is a relative value and always refers to the hwight of the parent element. But `html` has none.

Comment: Tried it with setting height explicitly and with/without the min-height property in-line

Comment: and tried changing html height to 100% and body to min-height:100% too

Comment: @deadman Added another solution to fix the sticky footer (and probably the background-color issue).

Answer (score 0):

even if you dont put `min-height:100%` its always at 100%. The height is always relative to the content always given that the height is not staticcaly defined

Comment: I tried all combinations of min-height and height on html and body element, thats why in trouble :(

Comment: YOu still didn't get the problem: a **percentage** does refer to the parent element. `<html>` has no parent element, so it's void. YOu can only use absolute values (in pixel, cm, em, ex or wehatever) here. Relative values have no effect.

Comment: Then how do i fix this issue, please help?

Comment: actually I was wrong, sory, forget that last comment. Setting the `height` of html to 100% should work, no need for min-height.